# Getting a count of records for the table with hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've got color and shade domains in my grails application.

```
class Color {
  static hasMany = [shades: Shade]
}

class Shade {
  static belongsTo = [color: Color]
}
```

Using criteria, how can I get a list of Colors where there are X shades? where X is a number that I can pass in.

I know that this returns entire list of colors:

```
def list = Color.createCriteria.listDistinct {
    shade {
       count()
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to get list where shade count is specific. I tried this but it didnt work.

```
def list = Color.createCriteria.listDistinct {
    shade {
       count() == 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) the `sizeEq` seems to be the the criteria method which fits your needs:

```
def list = Color.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    sizeEq("shades", 5)
}
```

Comment: I think parenthesis is required `Color.createCriteria().listDistinct...`